# How to check on SwiftMail if "spool" is enabled?

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

how I can check if spool is enabled via configuration?

In Swift_Mailer, I have a transport object and spool - but of course is private, in config:

```yaml
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

spool - is not readable for other classes.

I need that info to report the sending user that their message has not been sent, but it has been spooled.

Comment: but swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%' is not parameter - its service definition and how to read it - i dont know